# How to find images on Android device using Android File Explorer?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-file

I would like, as title suggests to find an image via Android File Explorer. I'm taking a photo and saving in on external storage but that part of storage is only available to app itself.

Basically, before I start Camera activity I have following code:

```
public File getPhotoFile(Contact contact, Context context) {
    File externalFilesDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    if (externalFilesDir == null) {
        return null;
    }
    File f = new File(externalFilesDir, contact.getPhotoFilename());

    return f;
}
```

Method in `Contact` class `getPhotoFilename()`:

```
 public String getPhotoFilename() {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    return "IMG_" + this.getId() + "_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
}
```

And in activity:

```
cameraButton.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        File f = getPhotoFile(newContact, this);

        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                "com.example.email.fileprovider",f);

        captureImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(captureImage, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
    });
```

I display full path, like this:

```
Log.i("PATH", filePath); //file path is member variable which just holds f.getAbsoluthPath();
```

What I get in output is:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.email/files/Pictures/IMG_0_20200428_001544.jpg
```

I've tried find that image in File Device Explorer, but no luck.

[image]

Comment: Your app is not `com.android.externalstorage`, and that is where you are looking, based upon the screenshot.

Comment: That was the closest I thought the picture was "hiding", I tried many different directories, no luck. Also, I started typing "IMG_0_20200428_001544", to try to find it like that, no luck. Apparently, I got no clue where that thing is hiding :)

Comment: Well, since you are storing the content in [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), you can examine this using your USB cable and development machine, using your standard OS file manager, by mounting the device as a volume. Or, you can try the device's built-in file manager. In both cases, you would be starting at `/storage/emulated/0/` and so would be looking for the `Android/` directory. In Device File Explorer, try looking in `/sdcard/`.